# Not able to upload huge files(in GBs) in AZURE BLOB using python

Tags: python, azure, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to upload files from url into AZURE BLOB using Python. My code is working fine for small sizes of files but when it comes to download and upload huge files it's not working and going to sleep mode.

following is part of my code which performing uploading task:

```
  block_blob_service.create_blob_from_path(path.join(container,dataset),
                          data.name,
                          file_name ,
                          content_settings=ContentSettings(content_type=mimetypes.guess_type('./%s' %url.split("/")[-1])[0]))
```

Please help me on this. I also tried with other methods like

```
  block_blob_service.create_blob_from_stream()
  block_blob_service.create_blob_from_byte()
  block_blob_service.create_blob_from_file()
```

Also used 'Timeout' parameters in above methods but not successful.

Comment: Please let the community know how you understood/confirmed " it's not working and going to sleep mode."

Comment: I left it for a whole day.. it stayed ideal ,no progress.

Comment: Setting `max_connections = 1` seems to work. https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-python/issues/190